# Remove localhost?

Tags: imac

I need to remove my 127.0.0.1 localhost from my host window temporarily to install a software what is the safest way to go about this?

I'm on a Mac running OS X v10.7.4.

Comment: This question seems very strange to me. I don't use OSX, but _no_ software should ever require this under any operating system.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a hardware loop back feature of all ethernet cards. The only way to remove it is to pull the ethernet card out of your computer. Not really an option on a Mac.

Comment: @JamesK, on my OSX box, I can run `sudo ifconfig lo0 0.0.0.0`, and the loopback goes away, but I can still ping other things.  It is a pretty silly thing to do though.  AFAIK, there is absolutely no good reason why you should ever need to disable the loopback interface.

Comment: @Zoredache - so that would seem to be the answer Mike is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What it seem you are looking to do is edit your host file. http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/

> Step 1 – Open the Terminal.app
>
> Either by start typing Terminal on the Spotlight, or by going into
>   Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal.
>
> Step 2 – Open the hosts file
>
> Open the hosts by typing on the Terminal that you have just opened:
>
> `$ sudo nano /private/etc/hosts` Type your user password when prompted.
>
> Step 3 – Edit the hosts file
>
> The hosts file contains some comments (lines starting with the #
>   symbol), as well as some default hostname mappings. Simply edit/remove 127.0.0.1 –
>   localhost.
>
> Step 4 – Save the hosts file
>
> When done editing the hosts file, press control-o to save the file.
>   Press enter on the filename prompt, and control-x to exit the editor.
>
> Step 5 – Flush the DNS cache
>
> On Leopard you can issue a simple Terminal command to flush the DNS
>   cache, and have your host file changes to take immediate effect:
>
> `1 $ dscacheutil -flushcache`